# Bootstrap 4 alpha6 | hamburger menu clickable but not responding on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

I built a navbar with the new Bootstrap 4 alpha6, and it all works locally, but on Heroku the toggle button is clickable but not opening the menu for links.
I'm using Rails 5 and HAML.

Here is the website: https://wiki-shmutz.herokuapp.com/

Here is the code:

```
%nav.navbar.navbar-toggleable-md.navbar-inverse.bg-inverse
  %button.navbar-toggler.navbar-toggler-right{"aria-controls" => "navbarNavAltMarkup", "aria-expanded" => "false", "aria-label" => "Toggle navigation", "data-target" => "#navbarNavAltMarkup", "data-toggle" => "collapse", :type => "button"}
    %span.navbar-toggler-icon
  = link_to "ויקישמוץ", root_path, class: "navbar-brand"
  %div.collapse.navbar-collapse#navbarNavAltMarkup
    %div.navbar-nav.mr-auto
      - if user_signed_in?
        .nav-item.nav-link
        = image_tag "profile.svg", width: "40", height: "40"
        = link_to current_user.username, edit_user_registration_path, class: "nav-link"
        .nav-item.nav-link
        = link_to "התנתקות", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "את בטוחה?" }, class: "nav-link"
        %span.sr-only (current)
        .nav-item.nav-link
          = link_to "יצירת ערך חדש", new_article_path, class: "nav-link"
      - else
        .nav-item.nav-link
          = link_to " כניסה ", new_user_session_path, class: "nav-link"
        .nav-item.nav-link
          = link_to " הרשמה ", new_user_registration_path, class: "nav-link"
      .nav-item.nav-link
        = link_to "אודות", articles_about_path, class: "nav-link"
      .nav-item.nav-link
        .copy-left ©
        מעגל הקוד השומרי
```

and in application.scss:

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a JS error `Uncaught ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined` on the page. That might be stopping the menu JS from running?

Comment: Yeah! that was it...
What a dumb mistake :)